# How to update all state object with same value apart from selected value in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React state object now I want to change only selected value property that time rest of the property should be same.

**This is working fine but suggest if there is better way to do it.**

My code:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false
  });
  
  
  
  
    const showModal = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === 'one') {
      setState({ 
        one: true,
        two: false,
        three: false
       })
    } else if (e.target.value === 'two') {
      setState({ 
        one: false,
        two: true,
        three: false
       })
    } else if (e.target.value === 'three') {
      setState({ 
        one: false,
        two: false,
        three: true
       })
    }
    modalOpen(true);
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the computed property name and object destruction:

```
const initialState = {
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false
  }

const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

const showModal = (e) => {
    
    setState({...initialState, [e.target.value] : true})
}
```

Comment: after target value true how can i reset (false) all the values?

Comment: @RohitVerma to set all values to `false` use:`setState({...initialState})`

Comment: `setState({...initialState})` this is not working...